# Line Break Across Two Columns

Tags: columns, line

I need to place a horizontal line across two columns to seperate my paper from my bibliography.

So, in ascii art:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,    minim veniam, quis nostrud
consectetur adipiscing elit,   exercitation ullamco laboris
sed do eiusmod tempor inci-    nisi ut aliquip ex ea
didunt ut labore et dolore     commodo consequat. Duis aute
magna aliqua. Ut enim ad       irure dolor in reprehenderit 

-----------------------------------------------------------

1. Reference 1                 5. Reference 5
2. Reference 2                 6. Reference 6
3. Reference 3                 7. Reference 7
4. Reference 4                 8. Reference 8
```

Is there a way to accomplish this in LaTeX?

The class file is based on the article class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is:

```
\usepackage{cuted}
.......................
\begin{document}
.......................
\begin{strip}
\hrule
\end{strip}
```

Adjust the value of `stripsep` to your needs (the default is `15pt plus 2pt minus 2pt`).